# Whose .equals() method is called to resolve hash collision in HashMaps?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, equals

***On every single article about HashMaps hash collision one thing is in common and my question revolves around that.***

Let me explain what i understand about hashmaps internal working.

**Saving two entries(e1,e2) with same hashcode using map.put(k,v)**

1) when the map.put(k,v) is called, hashmap finds the hashCode() of the key 'k'.

2) then it uses this hashcode it found as a seed for its internal static hashing method & gets another hash value.

3) then this new found hash value is mapped to the internal index of bucket.

4) then a Entry is added to the bucket.

**In case of a hash collision.**

1) same as normal, when the map.put(k,v) is called, hashmap finds the hashCode() of the key 'k'.

2) again same as usual, then it uses this hashcode it found as a seed for its internal static hashing method & gets another hash value.

3) the new found hash value is mapped to the internal index of the bucket, now there is a problem as it already has a entry at this bucket position.

**Resolution :** since the Entry is actually a simple linked list, the new item with the collided hash is stored at the next of the previous Entry.

**Fetching the entry e2 with map.get(k)**

1) hash generated from key & again static hash method called using the hash obtain from the key as seed.

2) finding the mapped bucket using the hash value obtained by the static hash method, now if there are more than one entries here **equals() method comes to the rescue.**

that is the linked list would traverse & keep on calling the "equals()" method until it finds the match.

Now my question is where is this so called equals() method defined ?

I opened the official documentation of HashMap & it doesn't override the .equals() method, **so where is it overriden? Or is it the default .equals() from the Object class ?**

Comment: Wait what? `HashMap` doesn't call it's own equals-method, this would make no sense, it calls the objects equals method which you're trying to insert.

Comment: @tkausl can you explain it in further detail ? Do you mean to say the default "==" in the Object class's equal() is used to find the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods belong to the class of the key object, not to the hash map.

The methods are defined in the `Object` class, but it is expected that the objects used as keys in a hash map provide their own implementation for both these methods. Therefore, it's not the *default* `.equals()` from `Object` class, it is the *specific* `.equals()` from the actual key class that gets called for collision resolution.

For example, if you use `String` objects as keys, the overrides of `hashCode()` and `equals()` provided by `String` would be used.

Comment: so by default if i do not specify equals() in the key , the references of Key class will be used?

This brings me to another question what if i add two key objects with same value but different references?

EX - 

String key1="game of thrones";
String key2=new String("game of thrones");

How will it affect the lookup ?

Comment: @SujalMandal The situation that you describe demonstrates precisely the reason why `equals` is used in place of `==`. You have two different object references that have values equal to each other, so `==` returns `false` but `key1.equals(key2)` returns `true`.

Comment: @SujalMandal The default `equals()` inherited from object will return true only when comparing two of the same instances, regardless of values.  `String`, however does implement `equals()` so your two string keys would be considered to be equal and therefore the same key.  It is typically recommended that all objects overwrite `equals()` and `hashcode()` especially if you are going to be using them as keys in a map.

Comment: @puhlen i typically ignored this thing till now but now i promise i will override equals() & hashCode() in the key class till the rest of my life :3